# как брать картинку из C:// диска и отобразить на JSP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, файловая-система, jpeg

Есть приложение на tomcat. Сам app - на Spring MVC. Есть функция загрузки изображения на сервер, сервер хранит изображение на C:// диске.

Полный путь выглядит вот так: `/opt/tomcat/temp/C:\path\/loadFiles/ves2_blog.jpg`

и проблема возникает при загрузке изображения на вьюху. Пробовал несколько вариантов с настройками Tomcat (server.xml,context.xml)(JNDI). Возможно я что-то неправильно сделал.

Вопрос как это сделать?? гугл пока нормально не помог.

И почему `c:\path\/loadFiles` создается внутри томката. В контроллере путь к созданию директории написан просто так:

```
String rootPath = "C:\\path\\";
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что томкат установлен на Linux, а в rootPath у вас - путь для Windows?

Comment: @Nofate интересно то что временная папка для файлов создается внутри томката..а не отдельно как в Windows.просто не знаком с linux..так как можно из контроллера можно передать картинку на вьюху?? читать да из ф.с. читаю но на вьюху незнаю как..

Comment: в начале думал взять из ф.с. и скопировать в папку images в webapp.тут то и возникали проблемы с путями..теперь хочется просто из контроллера на вьюху..

Comment: еще вот этот путь написанный для windows oна работатет и создается оно как видите вот по такому пути /opt/tomcat/temp/C:\path\/loadFiles/ves2_blog.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему. JSP страница выглядит вот так:

dinamycpage.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<img class="headimg2" src="photo2"/>

</body>
</html>
```

и 2 метода в контроллере

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "dinamycpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView dinamycpage(ModelAndView modelAndView){

    modelAndView.setViewName("dinamycpage");
    return modelAndView;

}
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "photo2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto() throws IOException {
    InputStream in=null;
    File f = new File("C:\\path\\loadFiles\\ves2_blog.jpg");
    in = new FileInputStream(f);

    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

Comment: Но вы по-прежнему используете в пути `C:`, хотя никакого диска C на сервере нет.

Comment: да.так вот в чем значит дело...я не знал что там нет дисков..значит там просто временные папки создаются ?? в home директории..